# WebAPI Preventing Race Conditions

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI POST controller method that basically just inserts a record with a quantity value into a table. I need to check that quantity against available quantity. The issue is that I can have multiple submissions occurring at the same time and want to eliminate any possible race conditions.

There are numerous ways to do this, but I am trying to determine the best approach. I thought of using a queue, but then the client device will need to make checks back to see state. I thought of using singleton pattern, but then the client will have to wait on release.

Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: can your controller be changed to handle 2 values the second value being a timestamp..?

Comment: It could, full control over the functionality. Just has to remain RESTful.

Comment: If this is all happen on one server, all you have to do is to create a static lock object and use this same lock object during update and read. this will prevent confusion on DB. Otherwise you can lock that record even when you read it. But this has nothing to do with Web Api. It is concurrency issue.

Comment: @T.S. Can you show an example?

Comment: @T.S.: you can't reliably base your concurrency solutions on locks at the app server side, just because this prevents clustering your app server in future. A "static lock" won't magically span two or more servers. Or maybe I am misreading what you wrote.

Comment: @DustinLaine: I would either have a lock at the DB somehow or an external queue of requests that is processed one-by-one (with the downside that clients have to check back the status).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not related to WebAPI, but to your data and the data management layer. WebAPI should not care about the data, its role is to accept requests and send back responses. The response depends on the input data, validation , business logic and so on.

Your question is the classic concurrency control question. There're many answers and the right one will depend on your system and architecture.

I assume your database transaction involves these steps? :
1) New Record Insert with qty
2) Quantity Update ( new total = total - qty)
And They must happen together or not happen at all?

One way to go is [Optimistic Concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control). Let the database (or your ORM (i.e Entity Framework)) tell you if the quantity counter is not stale, if it is stale, query it again and validate that the available quantity is still valid.

You'll need to google on how to implement the Optimistic Concurrency for your database. In a nutshell, it's a timestamp on the table that cannot be blindly modified. When an update is sent to the database, it contains the timestamp value that had been checked before the update, if it still matches, the transaction goes through, if the values are different, transaction is aborted.

Comment: The issue with using optimistic concurrency is the schema of the database. The available quantity is stored in one record while the sum of another set of records indicates the taken. So concurrent inserts into the second table could create the over grab of quantity. Which is what led me to the queuing solution. With that the client can wait and the queue would never be large so I was hoping to limit it in the API or BLL layer.

Comment: if all operations are done through your API, and there's no other way to affect the available quantity and the sum of "taken records" (i.e dba or another system inserting records) , then you could calculate the taken sum once (on a system start up for example) and save it in a counter of some sort? User it during transactions, and update it on each operation. This will speed up your system, and remove the need to calculate the sum each time.  P.S. I suggest you move this question to programmers.stackexchange. Since it's more of design question. It will have more views and ideas.